# Change Sort Icon in APEX 5 classic report

Tags: css, oracle, report, oracle-apex-5

How can I change the heading sort icon in a APEX 5 classic report?

The customer just wants to have his own sort icons for desc and for asc. He does not like the new APEX sort icons.

ORACLE says:

> Desupported Report Heading Sort Icons The following attributes used to
>   define the report heading sort icons have been de-supported for
>   interactive reports and classic reports: Ascending Image, Descending
>   Image, Asc Image Attributes, and Desc Image Attributes. Instead of
>   referencing images directly, Oracle Application Express now uses CSS
>   to render sort icons. For interactive reports uses the following
>   classes: `.a-Icon.icon-irr-sort-asc` and `.a-Icon.icon-irr-sort-desc` For
>   classic reports use the following classes: `.a-Icon.icon-rpt-sort-asc`
>   and `.a-Icon.icon-rpt-sort-desc`

I have no clear idea how that task can be made. I just know that APEX now uses CSS to render sort icons (`a-Icon.icon-rpt-sort-asc` and `.a-Icon.icon-rpt-sort-desc`).

It could be "Static Application Files" > `#APP_IMAGES#sort_asc.png` / `#APP_IMAGES#sort_desc.png`.

I am new with APEX, my colleagues say changing a sort icon in classic report was an easy task in APEX 4.2 but this easy way is no longer available in APEX 5.

Does someone has a piece of code and some hints?

Answer (score 1):

You need to define your own CSS classes `.icon-rpt-sort-asc` and `.icon-rpt-sort-desc`. They have to look like this:

```
span.icon-rpt-sort-asc {
    background-image: url("/i/custom_asc_sort_image.png");
}
span.icon-rpt-sort-desc {
    background-image: url("/i/custom_desc_sort_image.png");
}
```

Here you set names of images, which will be shown in a report column header. After that you need to use this CSS. Here you have two ways to do this:

1. Open page properties, go to `CSS` tab, place CSS code there. This isn't a good way, because you have to add this code to every page, where you need custom images.
2. Recommended way - create a css file with code above, put it in `/i/` folder, and change page template (`Shared Components`->`User Interface`->`Templates`-> desired page template -> `Definition` tab). In `Header` section add a `<link>` tag:

   ```
   <head>
     ...
     #PAGE_CSS#  
     #FAVICONS#
     #HEAD#
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="#APP_IMAGES#mycss.css" type="text/css"></link>
     ...
   </head>
   ```

where `mycss.css` - name of your CSS file. And, of course, you have to put your custom sorting icons to apex images folder.